# Can I use gcloud activate-service-account with impersonation (not static keys)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

`gcloud` has a --impersonate-service-account flag
`gsutil` has a -i flag

But I want to configure impersonation once in my current session and then know that all future commands are using that service account. So what I want is to `gcloud activate-service-account some-service-account-to-impersonate` WITHOUT a static key. Is this possible? Can gcloud setup impersonation for my current session like this without me having to specify --impersonate-service-account for every command?

Additionally I want to develop locally and run my app locally *as* a service account using impersonation. If I have the app configured to use implicit creds (google SDK should look for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or use the user's oath creds by default) I'm thinking it would be possible to run `gcloud activate-service-account` with impersonation then run my app in that same session and it will run with the impersonated account.

EDIT: per comments looks like this is what I want: `gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account [SA_FULL_EMAIL]`

Comment: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/

Comment: please add that as an answer seems like what I was looking for

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wrote an article that goes into detail on how to setup and use service account impersonation.

[Google Cloud – Improving Security with Impersonation](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/)

To configure the CLI to use impersonation by default:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account [SA_FULL_EMAIL]
```

To clear this setting

```
gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account
```

Comment: Just asked another question about how to do this inside a container. so developers can run apps locally in containers and still do impersonation the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345638/how-can-i-get-my-gcloud-user-creds-into-a-container-securely-and-use-them-to-imp